# iText7 .Net RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy error

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, itext7

I have been using iText7 .Net to parse text from PDF files in VS 2017.

However when I try to use the RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy as suggested in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969405/find-a-string-and-location-in-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-using-asp-net-c-sharp/44969966#)  to get the location of each text chunk, I get a "Nullable object must have value" exception in the foreach loop beginning.

The code for this approach is extracted directly from the test source of the iText7 library for RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy.

I have been unable to find where the error is coming from or how to fix it.

```
public void manipulatePdf()
{
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));

    System.IO.StreamWriter fos = new System.IO.StreamWriter(DEST);

    RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy =  new RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(@"[^ a - zA - Z0 - 9\s]");  //(".*");

    IList<IPdfTextLocation> locationList = new List<IPdfTextLocation>();

    PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy);
        parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());

    try
    {               
         foreach (IPdfTextLocation location in extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations())
         {
             if (location != null)
             {
                 locationList.Add(location);
             }
         }           
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a PDF for which that happens?

Comment: Sure. It is from the parsing example provided by iText 7 examples.  http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/raw/master/src/test/resources/pdfs/nameddestinations.pdf

By the way, the extractionStrategy..GetResultantLocations() object has the data (700+ characters) and looks ok to me.

Comment: The link you gave does return a 404. It looks like you had that link from the times the iText people used gitlab. They meanwhile have switched to Bitbucket, and during that change URLs changed, too. I assume it's the same file now downloadable from [this page](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/samples/browse/samples/src/test/resources/pdfs/nameddestinations.pdf). Unfortunately I have to tell you that I have no problem running your code against that file. I use iText 7.1.3 for .Net.

Comment: I am using 7.1.1.0 itext.kernel from Nuget - how do I get the newer version?

Comment: Well, actually I have checked out the iText 7 for .Net git repos and included the original projects into my workspace.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for your help.